# rails / check eager_loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, eager-loading

In development mode, eager_loading is disabled

Sometimes, syntax error occur, and having eager_loading set to false does not help to identify those. Is there a rails command (rake tasks) that could trigger such check ?

The point here is not to run test to find out, but to setup/use a command that would provide a similar result as a rails startup in production

Answer (score 0):

In case your app is not 100% test covered and some classes / setup might break in case eager_login is enabled (eg. production mode)

You can emulate such verification with the following (useful for pipelines before tests for example):

```
RAILS_ENV=production SECRET_KEY_BASE=xyz rails runner "some rails console command"
```